# Integration of Linea-Pro-iPhone-SDK ( referenced from Issues)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have downloaded the Linea Pro SDK from this link  http://www.datecs.bg/en/support/Downloads/4 and the demo app that I got with sdk is working fine no any build errors , But when i am trying to use this sdk in my project i am getting build errors in XCode 6.4

ERRORS:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"_tlvFind1", referenced from:

```
  -[RFViewController payCardDemo:log:] in RFViewController.o
  -[RFViewController rfCardDetected:info:] in RFViewController.o
```

"_tlvMakeTag", referenced from:

```
  -[RFViewController payCardDemo:log:] in RFViewController.o
  -[EMVViewController cryptoTest] in EMVViewController.o
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please help me for solving these build errors.